# How can I programmatically display a ViewFlipper's second child?

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper with 3 children.

I want to be able to display any of these children initially. So for example, maybe I want the ViewFlipper to load initially with the 2nd child and not the 1st.

EDIT:
I know I can use the getChildAt(int index) method.

**When a child in a ViewFlipper is shown, how can I get that child's index?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I want to be able to display any of these children initially. So for example, maybe I want the ViewFlipper
>   to load initially with the 2nd child and not the 1st.

Call `setDisplayedChild()`.

> When a child in a ViewFlipper is shown, how can I get that child's index?

Call `getDisplayedChild()`.

Comment: `setDisplayedChild()`  does not work good with `setInAnimation()`. If animation is added, ViewFlipper does not hide other items than which is shown, all views are put on top of each other

Answer (score 12):

bringChildToFront(child) does nothing but changes the index value of the child.

In order to bring a child to the front without using showNext() or showprevious(),

use

**setDisplayedChild()** and **indexOfChild()** together.

example

**vf.setDisplayedChild(vf.indexOfChild(child));**

where *child* is the *view* that needs to be brought front.

Thanks

Comment: Great answer, here is how I did:


`vF.setDisplayedChild(vF.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.view)));`