# How to save images correctly to sd-card?

Tags: android, image, save, gallery

I'm an android beginner with little knowledge of coding. I've implemented a save button in my viewfippler gallery but I'm getting two errors on this line "  Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromImageView(ImageView imageView);" in the saveimage() method. The compiler is saying there's a ")" expected and there's an illegal start of expression on the line specified above. The relevant code is below.

ViewFlipper.java

```
    public class ViewFlipperActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        findViewById(R.id.btnSave).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveimage();
            }
        });

       ........

}
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromImageView(ImageView imageView) {
        int viewWidth = imageView.getWidth();
        int viewHeight = imageView.getHeight();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewWidth, viewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        imageView.layout(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        imageView.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }


    public static void saveimage(){


        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromImageView(ImageView imageView);

        File f =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/HD GOSPEL LOCKSCREENS");
        if(!f.exists())
        {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
        f = new File(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) +"hdgospelLockScreen.jpg");
        if(!f.exists())
        {
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(f));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
   .......
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Change this line: `Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromImageView(ImageView imageView);` to `Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromImageView(imageView);` where imageView is an ImageView object.

EDIT: Also, your static function saveImage should take in the ImageView object:

```
public static void saveImage(ImageView imageView) {
```

Comment: You must create the ImageView first or pass it to the static function as I describe in my edit above.

Comment: How would I pass it to the static function ?

Comment: Your method should not necessarily have to be static.

Comment: Ok I'll keep that in mind. I've put saveimage(ImageView imageView); in my save onClick listener but its still giving me errors

Comment: Where is your ImageView defined? Is it in your xml? You need to grab a reference to it with findViewById and then you can pass that ImageView into your saveImage function, which as @NathanWalters need not be a static function.

Comment: Your syntax is still wrong. You need to pass an ImageView object to your method.

Comment: There are alot of imageviews within the viewflipper, how do I get the current imageview on display and pass that through? And yes the imageviews are in my main.xml

Comment: Well that's a rather more complex problem to solve. I don't have much experience with ViewFlippers, do you, @MikeOrtiz?

Comment: Each time the user swipes a new imageview is shown, the issue is how to grab the current image view object and passing it through to the saveimage() method

Comment: According to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265693/how-to-get-viewflippers-current-child-position), you can get the index of the view flipper using `flipper.getDisplayedChild();`. If you know the order and you know the index, you can call findViewById on the image resource to get an ImageView, which you then pass into saveImage().

Comment: It kind of makes sense but not entirely. That seems easier said than done.

Comment: You'll need to post more of your code to get a more concrete answer. I don't know what your ViewFlipper or xml code looks like.

Comment: The main.xml full code is here http://pastebin.com/kXBPFtk6 and also the ViewFlipper.java full code is here http://pastebin.com/jBvQewn2

Comment: Your code is utilizing some 3rd party libraries I haven't used before. My suggestion would be to maintain a constant list of your ImageViews.  `List<ImageView> myList; myList.add(gift); myList.add(besober);` etc. Then, when you call `int index = flipper.getDisplayedChild();`, use that index to get your ImageView: `ImageView img = myList.get(index);`. Then, pass that img into your saveImage method.

Comment: I've implemented what you've specified and the app is compiling but it crashes as soon as it gets pass the splash screen. Here is what i've implemented http://pastebin.com/WpcU2SvG

Comment: You need to initialize myList. Place `List<ImageView> myList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();` in your onCreate method before you add items to your list. In the future, you should always post the crash log, rather than just say that the app crashed.

Comment: Thank you so much its working now. One last thing though, how can i get the saved images to appear in the users gallery as soon as they exit the app?