# android widget TextClock fade in fade out animation

Tags: android, animation, clock

Does anyone know any working example of animate TextClock in Android widget?
I did quite deep research, and it seems that this is not possible as android widgets use RemoteViews which do not work with any sort of animation except ProgressBar which is not exactly made to animate between time changes on the clock.

Cheers

Comment: Can you explain Wich technology you use and more details about feature

Comment: How do you want to animate it, exactly? Do you mean to fade in/out between time changes?

Comment: I have a TextClock with separate fields for time and date in xml file and the button in main app file which switch between Remote views of date and time. I am trying to make switch between those animated on fade in/out basis. I would mind to also get fadein/out to do between time changes (minutes and hours increase) but I don know will this not be too expensive on performance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you correctly. If you have two `TextClock`s – one for the date, and another for the time – you can fade switch those. Beyond that, though, I can't really think of a way to fade between time changes; not accurately, anyway. Btw, please use @Mike if you'd like to comment back to me, so that I will get a notification. Since there's another user in comments here, we don't get notified unless you address us specifically, and I almost forgot about this question.

Comment: @Mike thank you for your answer. Yes, I would like to fade between date and time - this is the main subject of my question. I just didn't find anywhere way to do it for via xml fade in/out animations for RemoteViews. Animate between time change is only "nice to have" option, so I am not much fuss about it (plus I think i cost too much for performance).

Comment: OK, yeah, we can do that with a `ViewFlipper`. I'm not sure of your exact setup, but I threw together a quick, simple test earlier, to make sure it'd work as I was expecting: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Dk9YkcqxBgjEzW3Oi6P8X3gfmQ032Hw/view?usp=drivesdk. That just switches between the date and the time when you click on the Widget itself. It uses the built-in system fade animations, but you can use your own, instead, if they aren't quite what you're looking for.

Comment: @MikeM. I will try it tonight. Thank you very much. I will keep you informed about outcome of my test.

Comment: @MikeM. Your example is more than helpful. It works like a dream. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MikeM. I know this is 4 years old at this point, but since the linked resource is gone, how did you manage to stop the flipper from continuously looping and switching the views? I am using glance and combining with old remote views, and for me it just switches back and forth since i can't access the .stopFlipping() function from the code.

Comment: @Ionut You should be able to see that Drive file now; it just got shuffled into a private directory at some point. As for the `ViewFlipper` in this example, we flip it manually with `setDisplayedChild()`, rather than letting it do it automatically. I'm not sure which behavior you need, but manual is the default, IIRC.

Comment: @MikeM. Awesome, I did not think that i can use the setDisplayedChild() to "flip" the shown immage when i need. Although the animation seems broken when using this, it keeps flashing the previous image when fading. 
If you don't mind maybe it's best to add it as an aswer so i can also upvote you and ensure the code remains.

Comment: @Ionut I don't post answers here anymore, but please feel free to put one up yourself, if you'd want to. Thanks for the offer, though; I really appreciate it. Glad it helped. Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by flashing the previous image, exactly, but it might be an animation mix-up; e.g., wrong one set for the out animation, or possibly an incorrect ending value in the animation itself, etc. That's usually what it is whenever I encounter something like that in these kinds of setups.

Comment: @MikeM. What i mean is I have the flipper set as an fade_out and fade_in animation for out and in respectively. First pass is good, but after i set childIndex to last one, when I try to loop it by setting it back back to childIndex 0, 1, 2, etc, the fade out animation is fading from the wrong image. It's like it doesn't know what image to fade_out from and just fades out from all the images combined.

Comment: @Ionut Ah, OK, I think I get what you mean, but I don't really have any suggestions offhand. The two-child setup in the example works as expected , so if you get really stuck, you might try starting from there and building it up to your requirements.

Comment: @MikeM. It seems it's a known problem with using `setDisplayedChild` when using animations. The comment for the answer here speciffies all the old views get stacked up. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3678780/17158981
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @Ionut FWIW, I wasn't really sure what that linked comment meant the other day, so I updated my example to test this today, but I can't reproduce the described behavior. That is, it still works as expected for me with more than 2 children, and also with `ImageView`s in place of `TextView`s, to make sure that wasn't part of the problem. I'm not sure if you're even still working on this, but [here's my current test setup](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FaZN8prr_EAr9YVYiBN8tF6snab59dAL&usp=drive_fs), just in case it might be of any help. Cheers!